# My hilly landscape plane looks stretched and distorted when I start rendering. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Tags: modeling, rendering

I have a blender render I'm trying to create, but my landscape looks messed up when I start the render. I used the hair feature to insert the trees in case that's significant at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13Ibd9Cwjiz3ZQyAPbn-hfAFZyN4QwYaD/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you have your .blend file? Would you be able to share it for us to look at?

Comment: Hi @Onyx ! Here it is. It may be a little disorganized because I'm new to blender, but let me know if you're able to download and open the file without any issues. Thanks! https://drive.google.com/file/d/13Ibd9Cwjiz3ZQyAPbn-hfAFZyN4QwYaD/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

[image: screenshot]

Your terrain mesh uses the *Cloth* simulation. This and the *Subdivision Surface* modifier cause the problem.

Is there a reason for a cloth simulation? It is not a good idea to add a *Cloth* modifier to a dense mesh because the simulation takes very long and can even freeze Blender. With level 1 of the *Subdivision Surface* modifier the terrain has around 325,000 vertices. That's a lot for a cloth simulation. If you want to simulate a movement of the earth maybe try the *Displacement* modifier. It can be animated as well.

The rendering problem that you see is because the *Cloth* simulation has no data at render time. It uses cached data that is generated when you run the animation in the viewport or when you bake it.

The data is missing because the *Subdivision Surface* modifier has different levels for the viewport and the render.

The modifier stack works top-down. So first, the *Subdivision Surface* modifier subdivides the mesh, then the trees (particles) are added to this mesh, and then it is deformed by the *Cloth* modifier for each frame.

The *Subdivision Surface* modifier at the top of the stack has the default settings, *viewport level* of `1`, and a *rendering level* of `2`. That is, at render time the modifier adds more vertices to smooth out the model. Usually, that's totally fine especially when this modifier is the last one on the stack.

But in your case, when you render the image, the *Cloth* modifier cannot use the simulated data because it is simulated for a mesh with one subdivision, but the mesh actually has two subdivisions.

To fix this, either

- remove the *Cloth* modifier
- or move it up before the *Subdivision* modifier
- or decrease the render level of the *Subdivision* modifier to `1`

Comment: You're amazing! It must've been an accident while I was trying to turn a different plane into a cloth. Thank you so much. I thought I was never going to figure it out. Have a fantastic day <3